# Get sum of values from core data attributes displayed in an outline view populated from a tree controller

Tags: core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview

I am attempting to learn more about creating apps for OS X and have run into an issue that google has not been able to provide an answer for.  The example app I am creating is an RSS reader.  I have Core Data Entities of Folder and Feed, with Feed inheriting from Folder.

One attribute of Folder is unreadCount, with type Integer64.  Feed inherits this attribute from Folder.  The idea is that a display of the count of unread articles in a feed will be displayed and the total number of unread articles of all feeds contained in a folder will be displayed with that folder.

I have an NSTreeController that is managing the Entity Folder.  This tree controller populates an outline view with the titles of the folders/feeds and the unreadCount for each feed and folder (right now folder is just defaulting to 0).  The unreadCount is getting displayed via a value transformer that takes the integer count and returns its string version.  All of this has bee set up with bindings and is working fine.

The issue I am having is in getting the unreadCount of a folder to be the sum of all the unread counts in its feeds.  I have Googled for several hours and come across what appears to be a solution for tables populated from array controllers with the `@sum.value`, but this obviously does not work with tree controllers (from what I can determine anyway).

So, my question, how do I get the displayed unreadCount for a Folder to be the sum of the unreadCounts of the Feeds the Folder contains when the display is an outline view populated from a tree controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you rethink your data model. Instead of having `Feed` inherit from `Folder`, use two separate entities connected by a relationship: one `Folder` has many `Feed` instances.

Your count can then be supplied by the Model layer: `@sum.self.feeds`. This gives you the ability to write automated tests, too, and will simplify your life when you need something like the number of unread articles in a particular folder.

Comment: When I first started the project I went down the road of having separate `Feed` and `Folder` entities but was unable to figure out how to get them to populate the outline view, however I was unable to get everything populated into the outline view like I wished.  Basically a parent entity will always be a `Folder`, but they can contain other `Folder` entities as well as `Feed` entities (which will always be a leaf).  Is there a simple example somewhere that I missed that shows how to populate an outline view from a tree controller (and array controllers I would imagine) all with bindings?

Comment: And to continue that last comment, so the example would be an entity `Folder` that has a to many relationship to an entity `Feed`.  However the children of a `Folder` could also be other `Folder` entities.  I also tried having a `Tree Node` entity that had a one to many relationship with itself and had the `Folder` and `Feed` entities inherit from it, but was unable to get that mojo working either.  I feel like I'm on the cusp of understanding the problem, but there's some vital pice of info that would enlighten it all that I haven't stumbled upon yet.  Thanks.

Comment: I got it working with a super entity that both `Feed` and `Folder` inherit from with the tree controller controlling the super entity.  I was then able to use the @sum on the `NSSet` containing the children of the `Folder`.